# ReUse calendar on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

The page has datepicker and I want to use the same on the click of another div "abc". The another div exists on same page.
How can I do that ?
I tried using the class of existing datapicker to abc but no luck

Comment: can you post some code what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,I think I would work as expected. Now I can you as many instances I want to in all input types.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Wire up the JQuery UI date pickers
    $(".date-field").datepicker();       
});
```

```css
.date-pickers {    
    display:inline-block;
}
.date-picker {
     display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"> 
    <div class="date-pickers">
        <div class="date-picker">
            <label for="fromDate">From:</label>
            <input type="text" name="fromDate" id="fromDate" class="date-field" />
        </div>
        
        <div class="date-picker">
            <label for="toDate">To:</label>
            <input type="text" name="toDate" id="toDate" class="date-field" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Used :<div id="calendar" class="date rw-datetimepicker rw-widget" onclick="datePicker()"><button title="Select Date" type="button" aria-label="Select Date" class="rw-btn-calendar rw-btn"><span aria-hidden="true" class="rw-i rw-i-calendar"></span></button><b>+ Add Return Flight</b></div>  but it is giving me error in console as "datePicker is not defined"

Comment: you need to import `jquery ui theme` `jquery` and `jquery ui`

Comment: <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/theme.css"/>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>